# RecyclerView inside a fragment in android studio crashing my app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, crash

### My App is crashing whenever I try to put a recyclerView inside a fragment in android studio.

I can't figure out what is going on. I tried using a button to replace the layout in Fragment. The app was starting fine but whenever I click the button the App Crashes
Whenever I click on the App from my emulator and even from my phone, the App opens and immediately returns to the home screen and it does not show any error message.

## MainActivity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        frameLayout.setId(R.id.layout);

        setContentView(frameLayout);


        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout,new Fragment1()).commit();

    }
}
```

## fragment class:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    String[] Text={"he","hdhd","hdhdhdh","dhlsd","hshdsss","he","hdhd"};

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rows,container,false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView2);

        ImrulsAdapter Adapter = new ImrulsAdapter(getContext(),Text);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

## Custom Adapter Class:

```
public class ImrulsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImrulsAdapter.ImrulsViewHolder> {

    String[]Text;
    Context context;

    public ImrulsAdapter(Context context, String[] text ) {
        Text = text;
        this.context = context;
    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImrulsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rows,parent,false);

        return new ImrulsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImrulsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(Text[position]);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Text.length;
    }

    public class ImrulsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;

        public ImrulsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }
}
```

## Log Cat output:

```
2021-11-02 22:46:34.026 12332-12332/com.example.recyclerviewinsideafragment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclerviewinsideafragment, PID: 12332
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.recyclerviewinsideafragment.Fragment1.onCreateView(Fragment1.java:29)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1432)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7923)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3359)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2068)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
2021-11-02 22:46:34.047 12332-12332/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12332 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please edit the question n copy-paste the Log Output.

Comment: The most important piece of code is missing: the stacktrace of the crash. Please remove unnecessary bits too (e.g. Manifest + build.gradle, possibly other stuff too)

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: the stack trace says the recycler view is null. It looks like it can't find it in findViewById

Comment: Is there any possible reason, why that could be?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line inside the RecyclerView in XML:

**app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"**

In the end it should look like this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/yourRecyclerViewId" //RecyclerView2 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

Comment: I added that but it still shows the same error.

Comment: There is another solution, that you don't have RecyclerView2 id inside RecyclerView in XML, so that it doesn't find it. If you can, share the code so it will be easier to find the error

Comment: Thank you so much. I found the solution. I mistakenly used the row layout for my adapter while inflating the fragment.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found a solution. This was hard to deduce just from the code above :)